# awk and for-loop with multiple variables

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk

I am trying to write an awk script to read data from a txt file which requires a loop with three variables. Tried C like syntax and nested loops but no luck.

According to below link, C like syntax is also not supported with awk.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html

*The same is true of the increment part. Incrementing additional variables requires separate statements at the end of the loop. The C compound expression, using C’s comma operator, is useful in this context, but it is not supported in awk.*

**tst.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    printf "echo %s ", $1
    for (i=3; i<=NF;i=i+3) {
        printf " command1 " $i " command2 " $4 " command3 " $5, $i
        }
    print "command3"
}
```

**test.txt**

```
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"
"m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"
```

**Output:**

```
echo "a"  command1 "c" command2 "d" command3 "e" command1 "f" command2 "d" command3 "e"command3
echo "m"  command1 "o" command2 "p" command3 "q" command1 "r" command2 "p" command3 "q"command3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
echo "a"  command1 "c" command2 "d" command3 "e" command1 "f" command2 "g" command3 "h"command3
echo "m"  command1 "o" command2 "p" command3 "q" command1 "r" command2 "s" command3 "t"command3
```

Comment: Based on your output (`echo ,,, command1 ...`) you seem to be gearing up to pipe the awk output to a shell to execute. Don't do that. Just output data from awk (`e, c, d` etc.) if it's useful to use awk for that and then let the shell decide what to do with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with `printf`. The first argument is a formatstring, scanned for `%` characters.
With your input this buggy code will work:

```
awk -F"," '
{
    printf "echo %s ", $1
    for (i=3; i<=NF;i=i+3) {
        printf " command1 " $i " command2 " $(i+1) " command3 " $(i+2)
        }
    print " command3"
}' test.txt
```

Better is the changed `printf`:

```
awk -F"," '
{
    printf "echo %s ", $1
    for (i=3; i<=NF;i=i+3) {
        printf " command1 %s command2 %s command3 %s", $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)
        }
    print " command3"
}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to look backward from the current loop index and output based on `$(i-2)`, `$(i-1)`, `$i`. That would require a start of `i=5`, e.g.

```
awk -F, '{
    printf "echo %s ", $1
    for (i = 5; i <= NF; i += 3)
        printf " command1 %s command2 %s command3 %s", $(i-2), $(i-1), $i
    print ""
}' test.txt
```

In that case you produce the desired output:

```
echo "a"  command1 "c" command2 "d" command3 "e" command1 "f" command2 "g" command3 "h"
echo "m"  command1 "o" command2 "p" command3 "q" command1 "r" command2 "s" command3 "t"
```

Just another way to skin-the-cat with `awk`.

**Do You Really Want The Extra command3?**

Your output shows you want an additional `command3` at the end. This seems quite awkward, but if it is needed, just add it in the final `print` where the newline is output as you have done, e.g.

```
     print "command3"
```

Your output is then:

```
echo "a"  command1 "c" command2 "d" command3 "e" command1 "f" command2 "g" command3 "h"command3
echo "m"  command1 "o" command2 "p" command3 "q" command1 "r" command2 "s" command3 "t"command3
```